# How do I add UrlEncodedFormEntity to a MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a file that I want to upload so I have your standard MultipartEntityBuilder like this:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multiPartEntity.addBinaryBody("file", file);
```

I also have some form params that I send with the POST like this:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId",userId));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("taskId",taskId));
new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters)
```

Both work individually, My question how do I do both in one call?  I need to fold one into the other so I can make this in one HttpPost() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` content types. When sending a multipart request, you are using `multipart/form-data`, in which case you don't need to URL encode the content.  Just set the text directly

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", file);
multipartEntityBuilder.addTextBody("userId", "someIdWith@url$encodable<>characters");
```

[See the specification for more details.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4)